# How does pandas know to write the data to the correct column in a SQL table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to output the results of my query to a SQL Server table. I have code written like this, some dataframes some print statements, that I want to output to my table.

```
'''TABLE NAME COLUMN'''
df = pd.read_csv(f's3://bucket-name/{filename}', sep='|')
print(filename.split('.')[0])


'''CSV ROW COUNT COLUMN'''
numlines=len(df)
print(numlines) 


'''COLUMNS UNIQUE COLUMN'''
df_unique = df.set_index(unique_col_comb.split(", ")).index.is_unique 
print(df_unique)
```

I know I can use something like `df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append')` but I'm confused how it would know which column to output `df_unique` to, for example.